# Delete the rows which have NaN in every cells in python

Tags: python, nan

I have a data called `data` .

The problem with this `data` is that a lot of rows have `NaN`
I want to delete every rows which have NaN in every cells except `time`.
For example, I wnat to delete the row with `time` `2021-12-24 01:00:20` and
the row with `time` `2021-12-24 01:00:30` in this case.
The import thing is that I don't want to delete the rows with only a few NaN.
I wnat to delete the rows which have every cells NaN except `time`.
How can I do?

Comment: What is the type of `data`? Is it a numpy array, a pandas dataframe, ...? And if it's a dataframe, is `time` its index, or just a column and is the index hidden? (you wouldn't get these questions if you'd included a simple code example that defined that data)  In general [don't include code or data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I used                                                                                                                                  ```                                                                                                                                     # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np                                                                                                           ```                                                                                                                                   It's a dataframe.

Comment: And is `time` the index, or just a column and the image doesn't show the index?

Comment: I'm sorry `time` is not an index. There is an index in front of `time`. I captured partially.The index is hidden.

Comment: If pandas, use `dropna` with a threshold. Please update the tags and don't use images of code/data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it explicitly if you need to tweak it, or just using the function that `pandas` offers for this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, to_datetime

data = [
     ['2022-01-01 00:00', 1, 2, 3],
     ['2022-01-02 00:00', None, 2, 3],
     ['2022-01-03 00:00', None, None, None],
     ['2022-01-04 00:00', 1, 2, None],
     ['2022-01-05 00:00', None, None, None],
]
df = DataFrame(data, columns=['time', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
df['time'] = to_datetime(df['time'])

# explicitly select all the columns after the first, check if values are nan, 
# then get the indices for all rows where every cell is true - drop those rows
one = df.drop(df[df.iloc[:, 1:].isnull().all(axis=1)].index)
print(one)

# but pandas allows you to do it in one go as long as `time` is never nan
two = df.dropna(thresh=len(df.columns)-1)
print(two)
```